# minecraft.net login button doesn't do anything(changed browsers too)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been desperatly trying to login to minecraft.net with my mojang account.
But everytime I click the "Login" button it doesn't do anything.
I've tried to change browsers but that didn't change anything.
Also I have buyed minecraft with a code but I used the code on account.mojang.com because I couldn't log in to my mojang account in minecraft.net, due to the problem above.
Can someone please help??
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about using a website, not games.

Comment: 1. If you can't log in, contact their customer support: https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/emails/new?ref=footer 2. When you contact them, you'll have to give more details, like what it means that "clicking doesn't do anything". Does it actually not do anything, does the button at least change colour or do you get an error message? Be as specific as possible with everything. 3. This site is only for questions about games, not being able to log in on a website is off-topic here.